# Helm install locally but upgrade in pipeline?

Tags: pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I'm having trouble upgrading helm chart from a pipeline.
I run `helm install --name refund-robot .` from the root directory on my local machine to install the helm chart for the first time.
Later I have a pipeline where I update docker image and trigger helm upgrade.
In my pipeline I run this command:
`helm upgrade --install refund-robot .` but I keep getting this error:

```
Release "refund-robot" does not exist. Installing it now.
65 Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: existing resource conflict: kind: PersistentVolume, namespace: , name: mysql-pv-volume
```

Which is fair enough. I then tried running `helm upgrade refund-robot .` and I got:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "refund-robot" has no deployed releases
```

How can I make this work from my pipeline? Do I need to share some config with the pipeline?
What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the PersistentVolume called mysql-pv-volume from your namespace or use an other name instead.

*'kubectl delete pv'* command allows you to delete PersistentVolume .

```
$ kubectl delete pv mysql-pv-volume
```

Then you will be able to install your app

```
$ helm install refund-robot .
```